# Adding information into an array with super classes

Tags: java, arrays, superclass

The problem I'm having is with the superclass. I can't change the `new Property(...)` to another class called `House`. The only difference is the information in them, but once I change it I am getting an error stating that the constructor doesn't match but I thought that the `super()` should pass the information on.

This is how my Array is set up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Property [] Properties = new Property[25];

    Properties[0] = new Property (1001, 200, "58 Lackagh Park", "Dungiven", "BT47 4ND", new MyDate(15,05,2018), 5000.00, 800.50, 40.50);
    Properties[1] = new Property (1002, 500, "24 Jop Lane", "Kelflar", "VT57 5LP", new MyDate(10,06,2018), 12000.00, 1000.00, 60.00);
    Properties[2] = new Property (1003, 100, "Lot B", "Bandlebop", "LU49 3JU", new MyDate(01,07,2018), 450.00, 800.00, 50.50);
    Properties[3] = new Property (1004, 200, "12 Back Lane", "Galafray", "GA1 1Fy", new MyDate(05,12,2018), 50000.00, 1000.00, 80.00);
    Properties[4] = new Property (1005, 200, "43 Pop Street", "Jundar", "BY78 1JH", new MyDate(11,12,2018), 2500.00, 600.50, 32.90);
    Properties[5] = new Property (1006, 200, "123 Fake Street", "Dunlem", "BL09 4PL", new MyDate(21,03,2018), 65000.00, 700.50, 56.50);
    Properties[6] = new Property (1007, 200, "09012 Bakers Field", "Bristol", "LO87 D0N", new MyDate(15,05,2018), 5000.00, 200.50, 40.50);
    Properties[7] = new Property (1008, 200, "Unit B high Street", "LA", "LA58 7NL", new MyDate(18,11,2018), 20000.00, 1000.00, 90.00);
    Properties[8] = new Property (1009, 200, "1 Flabbergast Park", "Nubb", "HJ98 7NH", new MyDate(10,03,2018), 4958.00, 900.20, 20.50);
    Properties[9] = new Property (1010, 200, "29 Bakers Field", "London Town", "HU84 2JO", new MyDate(02,05,2018), 1234.00, 800.00, 40.50);
    Properties[10] = new Property (1011, 200, "20 Peliper Lane", "Dungiven", "BT47 4FE", new MyDate(15,05,2018), 4321.00, 900.00, 20.00);
```

Here is the `Property` class:

```
public class Property {
    private int PropertyNumber, SquareFoot;
    private String Address,Town,PostCode;
    private MyDate DateListed;
    public double Price;
    private double Rates;
    private double PricePerSquareFoot;


    public Property() { 
        PropertyNumber = 0;
        SquareFoot = 0;
        Address = "";
        Town = "";
        PostCode = "";
        DateListed = new MyDate();
        Price = 0.0;
        Rates = 0.0;
        PricePerSquareFoot = 0.0;
    }

    public Property(int PropertyNumber, int SquareFoot, String Address, String Town, String PostCode, MyDate DateListed, double Price, double rates, double PricePerSquareFoot)
    {
        super();
        this.PropertyNumber = PropertyNumber;
        this.SquareFoot = SquareFoot;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Town = Town;
        this.PostCode = PostCode;
        this.DateListed = DateListed;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Rates = Rates;
        this.PricePerSquareFoot = PricePerSquareFoot;
    }
//--------Getters and setters----------------//
    public void setPropertyNumber(int PropertyNumber)
    {
        this.PropertyNumber = PropertyNumber;
    }

    public int getPropertyNumber()
    {
        return PropertyNumber;
    }

    public void setSquareFoot(int SquareFoot)
    {
        this.SquareFoot = SquareFoot;
    }

    public int getSquareFoot()
    {
        return SquareFoot;
    }



    public void setAddress(String Address)
    {
        this.Address = Address;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setTown( String Town)
    {
        this.Town = Town;
    }

    public String getTown()
    {
        return Town;
    }

    public void setPostcode( String PostCode)
    {
        this.PostCode = PostCode;
    }

    public String GetPostcode()
    {
        return PostCode;
    }

    public void setDateListed(MyDate DateListed)
    {
        this.DateListed = DateListed;
    }

    public MyDate getDateListed()
    {
        return DateListed;
    }

    public void setPrice(double Price)
    {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return Price;
    }


    public void setRates(double Rates)
    {
        this.Rates = Rates;
    }

    public double getRates()
    {
        return Rates;
    }


    public void setPricePerSquareFoot(double PricePerSqaureFoot)
    {
        this.PricePerSquareFoot = PricePerSquareFoot;
    }

    public double getPricePerSquareFoot()
    {
        return PricePerSquareFoot;
    }
```

And this is what I am trying to put into the array along with the property information such as Property number price etc:

```
public class House extends Residential {

    private int Garden;
    private int Garage; 


    public House() {
        super();
        Garage = 0;
        Garden = 0;
    }


    public House(int Garage, int garden) {
        super();
        this.Garage = 0;
        this.Garden = 0;
    }

public void setGarage(int Garage)
    {
        this.Garage = Garage;
    }

    public int getGarage()
    {
        return Garage;
    }

    public void setGarden(int Garden)
    {
        this.Garden = Garden;
    }

    public int getGarden()
    {
        return Garden;
    }


.......
```

This is the residential class

```
public class Residential extends Property
{
    private int NumberOfBedrooms;
    private int NumberOfBathrooms;

    public Residential()
    {
        super();
        NumberOfBedrooms = 0;
        NumberOfBathrooms = 0;
    }

public void setNumberOfBedrooms(int NumberOfBedrooms)
    {
        this.NumberOfBedrooms = NumberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBedrooms()
    {
        return NumberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBathrooms(int NumberOfBathrooms)
    {
        this.NumberOfBathrooms = NumberOfBathrooms;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBathrooms()
    {
        return NumberOfBathrooms;
    }


    public Residential(int NumberOfBedrooms, int NumberOfBathrooms)
    {
        super();
        NumberOfBedrooms = 0;
        NumberOfBathrooms = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the *exact* error message, along with a minimal but *complete* example - for example, we don't know what the `Residential` class looks like. You can't call `new House(1001, 200, "58 Lackagh Park", "Dungiven", "BT47 4ND", new MyDate(15,05,2018), 5000.00, 800.50, 40.50)` because the only constructors you've defined for `House` have 0 or 2 parameters. I'd also try to isolate this to *one* aspect of coding - I don't think arrays are relevant at all here. (And it's not clear why you're using the `windows` tag either.)

Comment: this is the Error message "The constructor House(int, int, String, String, String, MyDate, double, double, double) is undefined"

Comment: Could you also add `Residential` class ?

Comment: You need to add it to your question.

Comment: sorry I'm new here

Comment: Well yes, as I said, you haven't provided that constructor - you've *onyl* got `House` constructors with 0 parameters or 2 parameters. Constructors aren't inherited. I think you should read more about constructors and what `super()` does, e.g. at  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Welcome then :) We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some tips. It won't take more than 5 min.

Comment: sorry i didn't add the constructors, I put them now so I have

Comment: And what exactly does not work?

Comment: so I'm trying to get the information from the property to add with the house variables so that I can put them into the array

Comment: `House` would need to declare the constructor thats being used: `House(int propertyNumber, int squareFoot, String address, String town, ...)`. You only declared `House(int garage, int garden)` and `House()`, which means you can only call `new House` when passing in either no arguments or 2 `int` arguments, opposed to the many arguments you are passing into `new Property`.